# Is there a way to setup a CI/CD pipeline directly for an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have a Django application that I plan on deploying to an EC2 instance. I was wondering if there's a way to set up a CI/CD pipeline without any of the services offered by AWS ECS, EKS or CodeDeploy but by Github actions or CircleCI?

Comment: According to my knowledge, we can achieve this on lambda function using zappa but not on EC2. Either way using lambda will charge you for the number of milliseconds compared to EC2 instance always running.

Comment: But there has to be a way to set up continuous deployment for EC2 instances, right?

Comment: [Check this link](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/continuous-deployment-pipeline/). I think you can configure the target according to your needs like EC2, EB etc.